# Comparação de Session e ViewState com String

Tags: c#, asp.net

Recentemente, recebi o seguinte aviso do Visual Studio em um código semelhante ao da imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entendo o que ele quis me dizer: ali está havendo uma comparação de referência dos dois valores (da sessão e da string "teste"), e isso sempre retornará `false`, pois qualquer valor guardado na `Session` nunca estará referenciado na string da direita.

Mas porque isso acontece? **Porque o Visual Studio não foi capaz de fazer a comparação sem uma conversão prévia?**

PS: O mesmo acontece com o `ViewState`

Comment: tenta colocar `Session["teste"].ToString()`

Comment: Sim, eu sei que isso funciona, mas gostaria de saber o motivo de precisar dessa conversão

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Porque o Visual Studio não foi capaz de fazer a comparação sem uma conversão prévia?

[Porque o retorno de `Session["teste"]` é `object`, não `string`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dhkksh8(v=vs.110).aspx). Não necessariamente tudo o que está em `Session` é `string`, por isso o aviso. O C# tenta comparar dois objetos, o que causa um *fallback* de operador, [mudando a natureza da comparação para referência](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx).

[Como dito em comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188737/compara%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-session-e-viewstate-com-string#comment390204_188737), use `Session["teste"].ToString()` para comparar corretamente.

Comment: Então a comparação entre dois `object` será sempre de referência, a menos que esteja sobreescrita?

Comment: Exato, mas reimplementar o operador me parece algo insano.